# SQL statement with a lot of join and parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a really long select statement with a lot of parameters and Inner join.

My first question: is there a way to make it more efficient?

<del>My second question is why doesn't it display anything in the textbox?</del>

<del>My goal is to display the house that comes from the search.</del>

<del>User first select everything in the combobox (all the parameters) and then my select goes through the table properties and display the houses available in a textbox</del>

```
        clsDataSource.mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\...");
        clsDataSource.mycon.Open();

        OleDbCommand mycmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT AreaSize.*, Bathrooms.*, Cities.*, Prices.*,Properties.*, Rooms.*, Types.*, Users.* FROM Users INNER JOIN (Types INNER JOIN (Rooms INNER JOIN (Prices INNER JOIN (Cities INNER JOIN (Bathrooms INNER JOIN (AreaSize INNER JOIN Properties ON AreaSize.AreaSizeID = Properties.AreaSize) ON Bathrooms.BathroomID = Properties.Bathrooms) ON Cities.CityID = Properties.City) ON Prices.PriceID = Properties.Price) ON Rooms.RoomID = Properties.Rooms) ON Types.TypeID = Properties.PropertyType) ON Users.UserID = Properties.AgentID WHERE Properties.PropertyType=@propertyType AND Properties.City=@city AND Properties.Rooms=@rooms AND Properties.AreaSize=@areasize AND Properties.Price=@price AND Properties.Bathrooms=@bathrooms AND (Properties.BoolAgent = true)", clsDataSource.mycon);

        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@city", OleDbType.Integer, 3).Value = clsHouses.location;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@propertyType", OleDbType.Integer, 3).Value = clsHouses.type;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@rooms", OleDbType.Integer, 3).Value = clsHouses.bedrooms;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@areasize", OleDbType.Integer, 3).Value = clsHouses.surface;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@price ", OleDbType.Integer, 3).Value = clsHouses.price;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@bathrooms", OleDbType.Integer, 3).Value = clsHouses.bathrooms;

        myadaptS = new OleDbDataAdapter(mycmd);
        myadaptS.Fill(clsDataSource.myset, "ResultSearch");
        tbSearchResult = clsDataSource.myset.Tables["Properties"];


        txtType.Text = tbSearchResult.Rows[idx]["DescriptionType"].ToString();
```

Comment: I would make a view in the database on top of your joins. And select from it instead of tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
        clsDataSource.mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\...");
        clsDataSource.mycon.Open();
        clsDataSource.myset = new DataSet();
        current = 0;

        OleDbCommand mycommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT AreaSize.*, Bathrooms.*, Cities.*, Prices.*,Properties.*, Rooms.*, Types.*, Users.* FROM Users INNER JOIN (Types INNER JOIN (Rooms INNER JOIN (Prices INNER JOIN (Cities INNER JOIN (Bathrooms INNER JOIN (AreaSize INNER JOIN Properties ON AreaSize.AreaSizeID = Properties.AreaSize) ON Bathrooms.BathroomID = Properties.Bathrooms) ON Cities.CityID = Properties.City) ON Prices.PriceID = Properties.Price) ON Rooms.RoomID = Properties.Rooms) ON Types.TypeID = Properties.PropertyType) ON Users.UserID = Properties.AgentID WHERE Properties.PropertyType=@propertyType AND Properties.City=@city AND Properties.Rooms=@rooms AND Properties.AreaSize=@areasize AND Properties.Price=@price AND Properties.Bathrooms=@bathrooms AND (Properties.BoolAgent = true)", clsDataSource.mycon);
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@propertyType", OleDbType.Integer).Value = clsHouses.type;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@city", OleDbType.Integer).Value = clsHouses.location;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@rooms", OleDbType.Integer).Value = clsHouses.bedrooms;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@areasize", OleDbType.Integer).Value = clsHouses.surface;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@price", OleDbType.Integer).Value = clsHouses.price;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@bathrooms", OleDbType.Integer).Value = clsHouses.bathrooms;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@description", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDescription.Text;

        mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        myadaptL = new OleDbDataAdapter(mycommand);
        myadaptL.Fill(clsDataSource.myset, "Properties");
        tbListing = clsDataSource.myset.Tables["Properties"];
        //FillCombobox();
        TAB2TXT(current);
```